# Cross sectional variance of random walks

Tags: variance, random-walk

Suppose that there are $J$ markets, and prices in every market $j$ follow a random walk. That is, for any time $t$, the price $p_t$ is the sum of shocks up to $t$:
$$p_t = \sum_{i=1}^t \epsilon_i^j$$
where $\epsilon_t^j \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ for all $t, j$.

Intuitively, one expects the cross sectional variation across the markets to grow over time. At time $t = 1$, all prices are zero so the variance is 0; however, when $t$ is large, prices may be very different across markets. Is it easy to calculate how the variance across markets depends on $t$?

*Note*: I do understand that, fixing a particular market, the variance of $p_t$ is $t \sigma^2$ (so grows linearly in $t$). But believe that this is a slightly different question.

Comment: I do not like superscripts as they get confused with exponents.  If the $p_{t,j} \sim N(0, t\sigma^2)$ are independent over $j$ then $E[\frac1J \sum_j p_{t,j}] = 0$ and $E[\frac1J \sum_j p_{t,j}^2] = {t}\sigma^2$ and $E[\frac1{J-1} \sum_j (p_{t,j}-  \frac1J\sum_k  p_{t,k})^2] = {t}\sigma^2$ too.  Is this what you mean by "the variance across markets"  or "cross sectional variance"?  In reality, different markets are often correlated over time and not independent.

Comment: @Henry Yes that's what I meant; I suspected that this was the answer in the end and thanks for confirming.